# facebook share button which returns a boolean

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I'm a newbie regarding this kind of coding, and I would really appreciate your help.
However, I would like to know if it's possible to make the share button return a boolean which gives true once the content has been shared.

I need it cause my website is about winning various stuff and the sharing action will give points to users.

Ps. My script is in php.

Thanks in advance, bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Facebook JavaScript API takes a callback that indicates if the post was successful:

```
FB.api( '/{page-id}/feed', 'POST', {
        message: 'Check out this cool link!',
        link: 'http://coollink.com'
    },
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            // post successful
        } else {
            // post unsuccessful
        }
    }
);
```

Documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Sorry for my great ignorance, but could you tell me what should I install on my script to make it work?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a service to write your code for you.  I recommend you read the quickstart guide on the FB documentation page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart.  If you're still having problems after that, describe what you've done, and what's not working, and you'll get some help.